# How many database tables will Magento create when you make a new EAV module?

Tags: php, magento

Can any one tells me

How many database tables will Magento create when you make a new EAV module?

please

Comment: What did you try? It's easy for you to count the table numbers before & after the installation.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I just want to know if i have 3 columns into my sample table like id, firstname and lastname then how much flat table i need to create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what you are creating, but the most simplest module will create the following tables

1. eav_table
2. eav_table_datetime
3. eav_table_decimal
4. eav_table_int
5. eav_table_text
6. eav_table_varchar